# Splitting many columns in a dataframe according to a consistent delimiter with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to figure this out for awhile now and haven't been able to apply any of the solutions I've found online for splitting columns in pandas yet. I have to apply the column split to 90+ consistently formatted columns.

Here's how I'm importing the file:

```
data = pd.read_csv(location,index_col=False,header=None)
```

Here's what my dataset looks like:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95
0   ITEM1   3$3 4$1 3$3 1$1 2$2 1$4 2$1 2$4 3$1 ... 3$3 2$2 3$4 3$2 3$1 1$1 3$1 2$1 1$1 3$1
1   ITEM2   3$3 4$1 3$3 1$1 2$2 4$4 1$1 4$4 3$3 ... 3$3 2$2 4$4 3$2 3$1 1$1 1$1 2$2 1$1 3$1
2   ITEM3   1$1 1$1 3$3 1$1 2$2 4$4 1$1 2$4 1$1 ... 3$3 2$2 3$3 3$2 3$1 1$1 3$1 2$1 2$2 1$1
3   ITEM4   1$1 1$1 3$3 1$1 2$2 1$1 2$2 2$4 3$3 ... 3$3 2$2 3$3 3$2 3$3 4$4 1$1 1$1 1$1 1$1
4   ITEM5   3$3 4$1 3$3 1$1 2$2 4$4 1$1 4$4 3$1 ... 3$3 2$2 4$4 3$3 1$1 1$1 1$1 2$2 1$1 3$1
5   ITEM6   1$3 4$1 3$3 1$1 2$2 1$4 2$1 2$4 1$1 ... 3$3 2$2 3$3 2$2 3$3 4$4 3$1 1$1 1$1 1$1
```

I'd like to split the columns according to each $ delimiter so the end result will look something like the following (excuse the formatting):

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  ... 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
0   ITEM1   3   3   4   1   3   3   1   1   2   2   1   4   2   1   2   4   3   1   ... 3   3   2   2   3   4   3   2   3   1   1   1   3   1   2   1   1   1   3   1
1   ITEM2   3   3   4   1   3   3   1   1   2   2   4   4   1   1   4   4   3   3   ... 3   3   2   2   4   4   3   2   3   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   1   3   1
```

What's the best way to do this in Python?

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, could you give an example few lines of the file itself (not the dataframe representation of it)?  That will help make it clear what's best done with a custom `sep` and what's best done as a post-processing step.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [regex character class](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#matching-characters) `[,$]` for the delimiter. This will split fields on both commas and dollar signs. So if the CSV, `location`, contains

```
ITEM1,3$3,4$1,3$3,1$1
```

then

```
df = pd.read_csv(location, index_col=False, header=None, delimiter=r'[,$]')
print(df)
```

yields

```
       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  ITEM1  3  3  4  1  3  3  1  1
```